# How do I set my ImageView to the top of the screen no matter what resolution?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

So I am trying to get the image to align with the top of the screen and there is currently a gap between the `ImageView` and the bar where you can see the battery etc.

It doesn't show the gap in layout preview but it does on my phone.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SomeActivity"
    android:gravity="center">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:src="@drawable/man"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
```

Comment: "tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"" This line hurts "in Android Studio". For the source of gap, please see, maybe, the container for this XML you pasted in question.

Comment: Try adding 'app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"' to ImageView. And also try removing 'android:gravity="center"' from parent constraint layout.

Comment: I think you mention about action bar in your question

Comment: Whats the heme of your `Activity`? That gap maybe is `ActionBar`?

Comment: There is no ActionBar there

Comment: The gap is literally just empry space, I can see the background color

Comment: @MarkDenom I suppose the empty space is due to the default padding of the container layout. You could check the `styles.xml` if it is applied to a specific layout or you can check if the containing `ViewGroup` has some padding or margin.

Comment: please add the theme of your `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

**I am using this. You can try this.**

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
   </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set any view on parent top to use this attribute

**app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/parent_id"**

this is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/main">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/demo_img_4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/main" />
```

another code using linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/demo_img_4" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

note: try another image

I hope it work for you

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add following code in your `imageView`

```
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

and other approach would be to use `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` as your parent Layout

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this one. In my case the gap was caused by an empty top action bar.

My issue was that I was using a fragment inside the `main_activity.xml`. All I had to do to fix the problem was to delete the line `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` from the container of the fragment in the `main_activity.xml` file.

I hope this helps someone to save their time.